# getting net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in axios reactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I've get request in reactJs to Node.js server given below

```
const response =
            await axios.get("http://xx.xx.xx.x:3002/api/products/allTimers/",
                {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.authorization_token }
                }
            )
```

and the console is given by

```
xhr.js:178 GET https://xx.xx.xx.x:3002/api/products/allTimers net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

how to solve this issue.

Comment: Think if you use `https` you need to provide additional credentials to the server. However, you are using http:// in your GET request so that does seem strange it would ask for that

Answer (score 1):

`net::err_ssl_protocol_error` may be due to the fact that you are starting a request to the URL starting with `https://` Test with `http://`