# React axios erroe

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, ssl, axios

I get this "AxiosError: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" error when I run my React app. There is no crash when I run my React code but the error is because it can connect to my backend application((spring boot application)) and try to get the data from the backend.

I Have updated my google chrome to the latest version.

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? [getting net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in axios reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61598236/14499516)